# Regex_replace in snowflake using pattern

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a regular expressions pattern which will remove articles(a, an, the), special chars(;,:,% etc) and expand abbreviation(inc.-> 'incorporation', & -> 'and' etc) in snowflake. I am able to do this in snowflake but it not completely correct. Below is my code. The issue is that i want to give pattern (for example output of 'a good book' should be 'good book' but string 'give a book' should remain as

```
'''
select REGEXP_REPLACE((
select REGEXP_REPLACE ((
select REGEXP_REPLACE ((
select REGEXP_REPLACE ((
select REGEXP_REPLACE ((
select REGEXP_REPLACE ((
select REGEXP_REPLACE ((
select REGEXP_REPLACE ((
select REGEXP_REPLACE ((


select REGEXP_REPLACE (

  
  (select REGEXP_REPLACE(concat (' ', lower('a book of the great man'), ' '), '(^an )|(^the )| 
  (^a )'))
  , '\\.|\\,|\\(|\\)|\\!|\\\\|/|£|\\$|%|\\^|\\*|-|\\+|=|_|{|}|\\[|\\]|#|~|;|:|''|`|@|<|>|\\?| 
 ¬|\\|')

  ), ' & ', ' and ')
  ), ' ltd ', ' limited ')

  ), '', '')
  '''
```

Comment: So, is the requirement to remove the articles from the beginning of the statements, that's what I understood from the example which you posted. And for special chars it needs to be removed from any occurrences or places?

Comment: Yes Srinath, thats correct

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using REGEXP_REPLACE, I suggest you write a UDF (JavaScript or Java), and use regexp of JavaScript (or java). It will be much cleaner and maintainable.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/user-defined-functions.html

Here is a sample function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform_text (STR VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
  var abbreviations = { "inc.": "incorporation", "&": "and" };

  // remove articles from the beginning
  var Result = STR.replace( /^(a|an|the) /i, "" );

  // remove the special characters
  Result = Result.replace( /(;|,|:|%)/g, "" );

  // convert abbreviations
  for (var abv in abbreviations) Result = Result.replace( abv, abbreviations[abv] );

  return (Result);
$$
;

select transform_text( 'A good, a:; bo%ok & hoyd inc.' ) as Result;


+------------------------------------+
|               RESULT               |
+------------------------------------+
| good a book and hoyd incorporation |
+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple tweaks on the excellent answer from Gokhan.

1. Convert the abbreviations prior to removing special chars
2. Special chars easier to remove with the ^ not one of these approach
3. Using \b to trap the word for the articles

[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform_text_2 (STR VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
  var abbreviations = { "inc.": "incorporation", "&": "and" };

  // remove articles from the beginning
  var Result = STR.replace( /\b(an?|the)\b /i, "" );

  // convert abbreviations
  for (var abv in abbreviations) Result = Result.replace( abv, abbreviations[abv] );

  // remove the special characters
  Result = Result.replace( /[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/g, "" );


  return (Result);
$$
;
```